# How to define public permissions in the base class of django model and generate different codename for each subclass

Tags: django, django-models

## django-4.2.6+python3.10

This is my base model class：

```py
from django.db import models
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        permissions = [
            ("restore", "Restore deleted obj"),
        ]
```

This is my subclass：

```py
class One(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField("name for you", max_length=200)

class Two(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField("name for you", max_length=200)
```

After I executed `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` it generates such records in the auth_permission table of the database：

[image: auth_permission]

This is not what I want, because their codename is the same, which will lead to confusion.

Because I have many such subclasses, all with the same type of permissions, but for different models, I don't want to repeat the definition in each subclass.

I hope that after running those two commands, it can generate different codename for each model in the database, such as：

Generate a permission with the codename restore_one for the one model, and generate a permission with the codename restore_two for the two model.

[image: expected]

I tried to find the answer in the official documentation of django, but I got nothing.

Perhaps we can start with the python manage.py makemigrations command. Can anyone tell me how to do it?